# Precision of SpeechRecognizer - Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Sorry for my poor english... xD
I'm writing some code to use Android's voice search. I have declared an intent like this:

```
SpeechRecognizer sr;
Intent intent_listener;
intent_listener = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
intent_listener.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent_listener.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,getPackageName());
intent_listener.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,0);

sr.startListening(intent_listener);
```

Then i implemented *RecognitionListener* class and i put some code *onResult* method. this work but it's not accurate and sometimes it don'understand simple phrases. it also take a lot to have a result... so i tried with the visible box (that you can normally use to search something on your phone) and that's perfect.
aren't the same thing? why one of them is more accurated then other? am i wrong something with parameters? i'm working with android 4.0.3. thanks a lot to everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` to `0`, rather do not set it at all.

To answer your question, the "visible box" and `SpeechRecognizer` are not necessarily "the same thing". They can be and probably often are, but there can also be cases where they are implemented by completely different speech recognition providers.